# Reject dropdown placeholder when validating in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

In my ASP.NET MVC4  model I have a required property:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a class")]
public string ClassName { get; set; }
```

This is bound to a drop-down list in the Razor view:

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.ClassName, new SelectList(Model.ClassList))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassName)
```

However, I have set the first element of `Model.ClassList` as the placeholder string `"Select one"`. If the user submits the form without choosing a class, it registers as valid because `ClassName` has a value of `"Select one"`.

How can I make this placeholder selection invalid?

Comment: You could remove the placeholder from the Model property and put it in the helper: `@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.ClassName, new SelectList(Model.ClassList), "Select one")`

Comment: @Forty-Two Thanks, that's worked! I didn't notice that helper overload. Please add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the placeholder from the Model property and put it in the helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.ClassName, new SelectList(Model.ClassList), "Select one")
```